# Does cache mean no condition statements till it expires?

Tags: python, django, performance, caching, memcached

**Hello Awesome People!**

With Django, I have a function that requires many calculations to display, but frankly doesn't need to be calculated each time you visit the view.

So I use Django `cache`.  Before accessing the function, I have a decorator that checks whether the user is active or not.

```
@access_to('active_user') # i.e `if not request.user.is_active: PermissionDenied`
@cache_page('one_week') # Not really that way
def index(request,slug):
    all_models1 = Model1.objects.all()
    all_models2 = Model2.objects.all()
    all_models3 = Model3.objects.all()

    # Calculation to check the Model that a user has visited recently
```

Let's have an example:

User is active at **8:00 AM**, and visits the view which has a cache that will expire after **one week**

Image the **SuperUser** just changes `user.is_active = False` at 9:00 AM.

Does it mean the user will always have access until `cache` expires?
Which data `cache` catches until it expires?

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the order of the decorators the `access_to` result will be cached or not.

Comment: in which order the `access_to` will be cached? So if I get it well, the user will still has access till the cache expires?